# A sufficient condition on $C^1$ positive functions for $f(x+y)<f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, functional-inequalities

I am trying to show that if $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a $C^1$ function such that
$$f'(x)<\frac{f(x)}{x}\quad \forall x\in (0,+\infty) \tag{$\star$}$$
then
$$f(x+y)<f(x)+f(y)$$

---

First of all, I showed that

- $x\mapsto \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is a decreasing function.

  Its derivative is
  $$\frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{f(x)}{x} \right )=\frac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x}\left (f'(x)-\frac{f(x)}{x} \right )$$
  Since $f$'s domain is $(0,+\infty)$, $x\mapsto \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is decreasing because of $(\star)$.
- If $x,y\in(0,+\infty)$ are two positive real numbers such that $x\leq y$, then $f'(y)<\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

  Because of $(\star)$, 
  $$f'(y)<\frac{f(y)}{y}$$
  The result follows from the fact that $x\mapsto \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is decreasing.

I proved the result through the following integral estimate. Let $x\leq y$. We can write
$$f(x+y)-f(y)=\int_{y}^{x+y}f'(t)dt$$
Every $t$ in the interval $(y~,~x+y)$ is greater than $y$, so we know that
$$f'(t)<\frac{f(y)}{y}$$
from the second point. So 
$$\int_{y}^{x+y}f'(t)dt<\frac{f(y)}{y} \cdot x$$
Since $x\leq y$, we know from the first point that
$$\frac{f(y)}{y} \cdot x<\frac{f(x)}{x}\cdot x=f(x)$$
so we have proven that
$$f(x+y)-f(y)<f(x)$$
Is the claim true? Are there any flaws in this proof?

Comment: Seems legit, but you only prove the statement for the case $x\le y$. So add another sentence saying the case $x\ge y$ follows from symmetry of previous argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$\frac{f(x)}{x} $$ is decreasing we have $$\frac{xf(x+y)}{x+y} < f(x) \wedge \frac{yf(x+y)}{x+y} < f(y)$$ adding both these inequalities we get $$f(x) +f(y) > \frac{xf(x+y)}{x+y} +\frac{yf(x+y)}{x+y}= f(x+y) $$

Comment: Thank you for this alternative way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seems great.
Beside the notation $$\frac{f(y)}y (x)$$

which i don't understand, the rest of the proof seems perfect.

Comment: That's product.

Comment: Yes, it indicates the product. I thought it might be more readable than  $\frac{f(y)}{y}(y+x-y)$

Comment: Oh ok. My bad, but i think $\frac{f(x)}y\cdot x$ is clearer.